# How to list files with last edited time and size

Tags: linux, sort, size

To make it simple, I need the info of files in a directory as below
filename datemodified size (sorted according to latest edited)

Answer (score 2):

`ls` has `-t` option to sort based on modified time (last edited one comes first):

```
ls -lt
```

If you want human readable size, use:

```
ls -lht
```

Take a look at `man ls`.